# How to create chart or line graph in Python with strings in csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, matplotlib

My csv file contains $ signs and commas for numbers (screenshot attached)[image].

How to create a simple line graph with it. Do i have to convert it and remove the $ sign?

```
 price_index = pandas.read_csv("houses_price_index_losangeles.csv") 

 price_index['Los Angeles'] 
 price = price_index['Los Angeles'] 
 month = price_index['Month-Year'] 
 plt.plot(price,month,'g',label='Tarzana')
 plt.title('Houses for sale')
 plt.ylabel('Prices')
 plt.xlabel('Year')

 plt.legend()

 plt.grid(True,color='k')

 plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, this is numeric data. You should do that.

Comment: Convert it with `price_index['Los Angeles'] = price_index['Los Angeles'].str.replace('[^\d.]', '').astype(float)` And then plot.

Comment: what about "Jan-90" how to make it a number 90? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove all the non-numeric characters from the prices columns, and convert the `Month-Year` column into a `datetime` object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

price_index = pd.read_csv("houses_price_index_losangeles.csv", delimiter='\t') 
price_index['Los Angeles'] = price_index['Los Angeles'].str.replace('[^\d.]', '').astype(int)
price_index['Month-Year'] = pd.to_datetime(price_index['Month-Year'], format='%b-%y')

price_index.plot(x='Month-Year')
plt.title('Houses for sale')
plt.ylabel('Prices')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True, color='k')
plt.show()
```

Giving you:

[image: matplotlib plot]